# Implement Dark Mode to PDF

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

I am using com.github.barteksc:pdf-view-pager:1.0.3 for loading pdf on my app through internet and i want to implement Dark Mode give option to user to view PDF in dark mode or Regular mode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far and what were the results you got?

Comment: I think that yoz need to update to `'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'` and then to use `.nightMode(true)`

Comment: @Shmuel I build app for viewing all study resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update to `'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'`or higher and then to use `.nightMode(true)`.

Comment: i tried this but view like night mode doesn't work